# Math textbook style with what follows

Tags: writing, technical

I am proofreading a math textbook. The author writes, "Ask students the following questions. Have them write their answer in their math journal. Then call on several students to check answers." My question involves the statement that questions will follow and then I see two or even three more lines of text before the questions. It does not seem logical to me to use "the following" when the questions do not follow, but I would like your opinion(s) on this matter.

Comment: Things can "follow" without "immediately following". A duckling can be 7th in line behind his mother, but still be "following" her. This is in fact why we use the construction "immediately following", to distinguish that special case.

Comment: It's not illogical to use 'the following' here, but pragmatics dictates that they shouldn't be 60 pages later. 3 intervening but relevant lines (as here), fine. 10 lines, I'd switch to '... the questions below'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends how many questions there are.  If there are only a few you could suggest s/he changes it to read:

Ask students the following questions:

- List questions

Next, have them write their answer in their math journal.

However, if there are a lot of questions it is probably neater to include them all as a separate section, in which case it might be clearer to adjust the text to say:
Ask the students the questions listed in section x.  Have them write....

Answer (score 1):

It is common in mathematical writing to use "below" instead of "following" in an instance like this or, indeed, in an instance with even more separation.

For example, I am reading an article in a scholarly math journal right now, and one sentence reads: "Exercise 1 below explores some related identities." *Three pages later*, there is a section entitled "Exercises"!

In your context, I think "following" is reasonable. But it would also be reasonable to write something like, "Ask the questions listed below. Have the students write their answers in a journal" etc.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is less about logic than it is about readability.  Yes, logically, the questions could be 4 chapters later.  Still not good writing.  But this isn't writers.stackexchange.com so this isn't the best place to answer that.

But if it was my book I'd want my proof reader to at least point this issue out.  Just like those giving speeches should avoid false endings, a writer should avoid false introductions.